# Wordpress multisite: siteurl of a subdomain keeps changing by itself

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

I am having an annoying issue with a Wordpress multisite running Woocommerce. Currently it has the following multisite setup:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/en/
```

The subdirectory site's `www.domain.com/en/` setup options for **Siteurl** and **Home** are as follows:

```
Siteurl: www.domain.com/en/
Home: www.domain.com/en/
```

This is the setup that works as expected.

However, for whatever reason, the subdirectory site's **Siteurl** value changes occasionally by itself from `www.domain.com/en/` to `www.domain.com/`. This will cause the subdirectory site's admin part to become unaccessible.

I have had this issue since the very beginning and I cannot figure out why Wordpress is behaving like this. I have to manually change the Siteurl value back to `www.domain.com/en/` every time. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue:

Remove define('RELOCATE',true); from your wp-config.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, since I have updated to Wordpress 5.2, this issue hasn't happened anymore. However, if this were to happen again, I will try this solution and report.

Comment: Valar Dohaeris!